# Fastest way to grep list 1000 records in another million of records in a file in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, awk

What is the fastest way to grep a list of 1000 records in another million of records in a file in Linux.

Let's say these are my sample records :

```
1,,EE1,1000,WAT,EEE,20160222T02:00:15+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,,vEEE,,47126469f184fee9a80664d952d7fea7,50278774602,95223904,140495221530736,21001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,C
0,,EE1,1000,WAT,EEE,20160222T02:00:15+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,20160222T02:00:15+0400,,vEEE,47126469f184fee9a80664d952d7fea7,50278774602,,,21001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
1,,EE1,1000,WAT,EEE,20160222T02:00:15+0400,20181231T23:59:59+0400,20160521T11:07:25+0400,,vEEE,47126469f184fee9a80664d952d7fea7,50278774602,0095223904,140495221530736,21001,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,H
```

If I grep `50278774602`, the values will come in three rows. I have developed one script using for loop on the same. I have a list of such numbers in a file and I am searching the value in the big file (millions of row) and I need only the last occurrence of such row containing my grep pattern.  It works perfectly with a `for` loop but my concern is it's taking a huge time.

My script :

```
for i in `cat /home/admin/pnd_tmp`; do
    grep $i /test/done/TEST_RT* | tail -1 > /home/admin/pnd_fin |
    awk -F "," '{if ( $1 == "4" ) print $13 }' > /home/admin/pnd_tmp_fin
done
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Your script doesn't seem like it can be correct (even aside from performance considerations): it overwrites `/home/admin/pnd_tmp_fin` on each pass through the loop, discarding all of its work so far. So your script can be made much faster, without impacting its correctness, by just skipping to the last pattern in `/home/admin/pnd_tmp`.

Comment: Also, the `awk -F "," '{if ( $1 == "4" ) print $13 }'` part doesn't correspond to anything in the description.

Comment: That is just manipulation , if i get each row in a file manipulation would be easier. 

Its taking much time for search  i need better command.

Comment: What programming languages do you know?

Comment: @ Ruakh - Shell scripting as of now.

Comment: I assume the patterns are in the file `pnd_tmp`. You can use that with the option `-f`. Since the patterns also seem to be fixed strings rather than regular expressions, you can also use `-F`.

Comment: Using the `if` like this in `awk` seems rather change, why not use `awk` as intended and `'$1=="4"{print $13}'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tac and grep (GNU) you can use

`tac /test/done/TEST_RT* | grep -m 1 $i`

Inside your for loop. This is much faster than finding all matches and picking only the last one.

Comment: i have much larger file , takes much time . 

I have tried with awk :

awk -F, '!a[$13]++' file

But unfortunately it takes only first occurrence of the value inside the file , i need the latest occurrence of the value inside the file.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously performance issues come from the fact that for each line in the bigger file you grep over all your data again and again. Perhaps you should take a different approach. Without knowning the specific domain of the problem, I'd guess something like:

1. first sort the data in `/test/done/TEST_RT*` in some way that would allow O(1) access - for example break it down into multiple files in a hashed directory structure based on the value of `$1`
2. Then pass over the lines in `/home/admin/pnd_tmp`, accessing the data from the right file for each line and manipulating it using `awk`.

Essentially, you do a two-pass process where you sort the data first and access it much faster when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your problem,

```
grep -f PATTERNFILE HUGEFILE | tail -n 1
```

will find the last line in HUGEFILE, which contains any pattern in PATTERNFILE.

In case you are looking for the last of occurance of *every* pattern in PATTERNFILE, I wouldn't do this with shell scripts (although it would be easily possible) for performance reason, but use for instance Ruby or Perl. If you are going for this solution and need help, please clarify it in your posting.